# desborde modal php boostrap

Tags: php, div, table, bootstrap

Como puedo evitar esto en un modal con Boostrap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo reviso y esta bien anidado

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Datos iniciales del colaborador</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="datos" action="ingresarSeguimiento.php" method="post">
            <table class="table table-sm bg-light">
<tbody>
<!-- contenido de la tabla -->
</tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <input id="boton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" form="datos" value="Iniciar seguimiento">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

y si alguien me puede informar por que hay veces que el boton de cerrar no funciona, es aleatorio y lo reviso con la consola y no veo ningun error....
GRACIAS

Comment: Que problema presenta tu codigo?

Comment: El error es **MUY** obvio!! Por si no lo ves, te lo digo... **ahí falta mitad del código!** Imagino que habrá sido un error al pegar el código, porque si no, no me explico cómo pretendes que te ayude alguien sin ver qué has hecho. Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y añadas tódo el código relacionado

Comment: a simple vista ninguno, pero no se por que desborda del modal, y por que es aleatorieo el funcionamiento del boton cerrar

Comment: si Benito-B ya la edite y coloque todo el codigo del modal el modal lo llamo por include a la pagina inicial con <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <?php include "modalBuscColab.php";?>
                </div>

Comment: En vez de organizar los vamos del formulario con un elemento de tipo tablet, prueba hacer un sistema de grillas con Bootstrap